# How do I get the score for plotting the ROC curve for a genetic algorithm classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, genetic-algorithm, roc

I am trying to get the ROC curve for a binary (good/bad) classifier that I used for a project. This classifier uses the genetic algorithm to make predictions.

E.g. a test chromosome given by [1.0,0.5,0.4,0.7] is said to be good if it matches another chromosome, say [0.8,0.5,0.3,0.6]. And by matching, I mean having an [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) value (from the other chromosome) below a particular value.

I have completed the classification of the 600 instances, and I have the final confusion matrix (by this matrix I mean the four-valued table from which we can we calculate the final TPR and FPR), the correct classification labels for each instance, and also all the predictions for each instance.

I have read this documentation about ROC curve, *[Receiver operating characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic%22Receiver%20operating%20characteristic%22)* and *[Tools for Machine Learning Performance Evaluation: ROC Curves in Python](http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2010/09/tools-for-machine-learning-performance.html)*. How do I proceed to get the ROC curve?

With my final four-valued table I think I can only plot a single point in the curve. The attached links above keeps mentioning that I need a score (i.e a probability score), but I don't know how I can get this for a genetic algorithm classifier. But how do I use the knowledge of each instance's prediction to create a kind of continuous ROC curve?

Disclaimer: I am new to the ROC plotting thing, and I am coding this in Python - hence, I attached the Python-related ROC documents.

Comment: ROC curves are defined for binary classification - where the outcome can take two values. You have a minimization problem, that's not a task for a ROC curve.

Comment: @Calimo, I am not doing a minimization problem. Its a binary classification. I.e if an instance matches an item say a, then its positive. Else, its negative. Isn't this a binary classification? Were I think you misinterpreted is where I talked about "if a distance is below so and so...that was just a matching criteria to determine when to say negative or positive. My model is pretty much utilizing a modified form of GA to perform a task (like classification), and not really using GA to perform a minimization or maximization problem.

Comment: no this is not the definition of binary classification. Binary classification is when you assign an observation to one or another out of two groups. Then you check if the assignment is correct. Here you have more than two chromosomes so it is not binary classification.

Comment: the chromosomes in my technique are similar to say instances. At the long run, I still assign an observation to one or another out of two groups. Would have loved to go into much details on what I mean, but I think my question and my comments has enough detail. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter how did you create your classifier. In the end, your model is simply giving a positive label iff `||x - x_i|| < T`, where `T` is some predefined threshold. ROC curves are parametrized with exactly this kind of things - scalar value, which you can change to make things more biased toward classifing as positive or negative. So simply go through multiple values of T, compute metrics for each value and this will create your ROC curve. That's all!

Comment: thanks I will give this a try i.e iterating through various values of T and using the metrics to plot my ROC curve.